# Java - How to interact with website input elements using android application

Tags: java, android, html

I'm currently working on an application that opens http://www.marinetraffic.com/ais/ (I don't own this website) in the user's phone browser when they press a button by using an ACTION_VIEW Intent. I would like the application to be able to fill in the "Go to Area..." search box on the website and simulate the user pressing the ENTER key.

Comment: Wasn't this question already posted some time ago?

Comment: My flagging history says yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731788/interaction-between-android-application-and-website-search-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I see is to do this with Javascript. First load the page, and then interact with the page this way:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { JS CODE THAT INTERACT WITH PAGE })()");
```

Also, before loading script make sure that JS is enabled in WebView

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Also, in this case better to do some check in your javascript and to notify application about successes and failures of your actions. To do this add javascript interface

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(/*your javascript interface*/)
```

[Building Web Apps in WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)